# What formats of video will play in emulator?

Tags: android, video, emulation, formats

What formats of video file are supported in the Android emulator?

I understand that it probably won't play in real time, but what ones will play at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It supports `H.263` encoding and decoding, `H.264 AVC`  and `MPEG-4 SP` both only decoding.

On an emulator the playback quality in terms of speed or lags might be a bit cumbersome.

Checkout the chart of all [supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for more information.

Comment: In particular, your ability to play video in an emulator will be governed by the native speed of the emulator (e.g., the Honeycomb preview is more of a dog than anything before it) and the speed of your underlying PC. For example, on some older emulators, I can play back an MP4 file fine on a quad-core 2.66GHz Linux machine with a 512MB PCI-X video card. That same MP4 will not play back on a dual-core 2.5GHz Windows/Linux notebook with a 128MB discrete graphics card. If you're serious about video, you're going to need hardware.

Comment: Worth noting that with H.264 only the _baseline_ profile is actually supported.  I nearly drove myself crazy trying to figure out why a video was non-playable despite seemingly being compatible.  Turns out it was encoded using the _main_ profile.  Which works fine on an actual Android device, but is unsupported in the emulator.

Answer (score 12):

The secret is that the emulator will play the MP4 baseline profile, while real devices will also play better MP4 profiles.

In order to get a video file that plays properly in the emulator, try these settings:

```
ffmpeg -i inputvideo.wmv -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline outputvideo.mp4
```