# Video on Android Virtual Devices?

Tags: android-emulator

I have installed Android SDK Manager to test web sites on Android Virtual Devices.

I have problem in seeing videos on it:
I hear audio normally but I see only black instead of video (controllbar is OK).
The video is encoded H264/AAC 1Mbs and plays well on browsers and iPhones emulator.

Do I have to add new hardware properties ?
You can see [my configuration here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17712598/Capture%202012-02-10%20%C3%A0%2010.45.52.png)

Thanks for your help
Paul

Comment: Are you receiving any messages, such as "This video cannot be played"?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no specific hardware properties that are required for video playback. The emulator will only play a limited subset of video encodings while a real device will support a more comprehensive set. GPU emulation might help if your emulator is too slow to play back the video, but is not required.

Make sure your video is encoded using a baseline profile that can be played back in the Android emulator. This answer might help: [What formats of video will play in emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910222/what-formats-of-video-will-play-in-emulator)