# Xamarin Android Player - Can't play this video

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm using Android's VideoView to play an embedded video in my app. It works fine on my device but I keep getting a "Can't play this video" message and a black screen in the Xamarin Android Player.

[image: error message]

The corresponding error log looks like this:

```
Unable to play video
[MediaPlayer] Error (1,-38)
[VideoView] Error: 1,-38
```

I found a few posts regarding this error but none of them helped me solving this issue and I'm not able to find a proper description for this status code.

My C# code looks like this:

```cs
videoView = new VideoView (Context);
base.SetNativeControl (videoView);
videoView.SetOnErrorListener (new ErrorListener ());

string fileName = e.NewElement.FileSource;
fileName = fileName.ToLower ().Substring (0, fileName.LastIndexOf ("."));
int resourceID = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier (fileName, "raw", Context.PackageName);
var fullPath = String.Format ("android.resource://{0}/{1}", Context.PackageName, resourceID);

videoView.SetVideoPath (fullPath);
videoView.RequestFocus ();
videoView.Start ();
```

Comment: what format is your video? mp4?

Comment: yes, the format is mp4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the type of encoding that the emulator supports, if you install ffmpeg, if your on a mac by running these commands:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew install ffmpeg
```

then process your video file with:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

and try to play the output it wont show that error but it will be a blank video (just a black screen). So I think the issue is just getting the right encoding, have tried some different encodings but all seems to just show a black screen.

Will do some more digging but for the time being it seems to be just the emulator does not support your encoding.

**EDIT**

Ok so I got the videoplay working, I processed the video with:

```
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 500k -vf scale=-1:360 -threads 0 -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 96k output.mp4
```

Check this [site](https://www.virag.si/2012/01/web-video-encoding-tutorial-with-ffmpeg-0-9/) for the ffmpeg parameters.
I setup my `VideoView` like so:

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        VideoView videoView;
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            videoView = FindViewById<VideoView> (Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);
            videoView.SetMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            videoView.SetVideoPath ($"android.resource://{PackageName}/{Resource.Raw.output}");
            videoView.RequestFocus ();
            videoView.Start ();
        }
    }
```

This seems to work on the Xamarin Android Player but only for API versions 16(JellyBean) and 19(Kitkat). 21 (lollipop) just doesn't load the video.

Then I downloaded the [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) Emulator (need to create an account but its free for personal use) to check if it was the Xamarin Player or not. It works on all (16,17,18,19,20 + 22) apart from 21(lollipop). looks like something is wrong with the emulators for 21, I did all my testing on nexus 4 emulators. So if you want tot est video playback I would try to avoid emulators with API 21.

Comment: After processing the video it plays fine on my mac but on the emulator it just produces a black screen as you described. At least the error message disappeared. Any idea which encoding is supported on the Xamarin Android Player? Cheers!

Comment: Yeah its the same on my machine, not too sure about what ones are supported tho, this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/4910269/1107580 seems to think its H.263. Going to try to encode it using that a see if it plays

Comment: I've seen that post before and tried H.263 Encoding without any luck. But feel free to give it a try as well.

Comment: Tried H.263 but still just getting a black screen too. Noticed some people saying they can get video to play but it's slow. Also the browser seems to be able to play video on the emulator but I would assume that isn't using a videoview

Comment: I processed my video by using the command you posted in your EDIT. In fact I just needed to process it using the baseline profile:  `ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -profile:v baseline output.mp4`. I'm now able to play the video on API 16 but still getting a black screen and error message on API 21. Do you think this will cause a problem on physical devices? If not, I would just go on and ignore that it's not working on the emulator. Cheers!

Comment: Just test my project on a real device (nexus 5) running API 21 and it plays the video fine.

Answer (score 2):

Different Android OS versions support different combinations of audio and video encodings within the video container. So it depends what version your Android Player is emulating. For the table see http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core

Comment: I've seen that table before and according to the described media formats it should work on my emulator (running Lollipop API 22). The video I'm trying to play uses H.264 AVC encoding and mp4 container format. Curious whether there is some sort of limitation on the xamarin android player itself.